# $f(x) = \ln( \exp(x/2) + \exp(-x/2) )$ is a concave function of $x^2$

Tags: derivatives

In one paper I see this sentence. Not quite sure how to verify it, I take the form 
$f(x^2)$, and take the second derivative w.r.t. $x^2$, using the chain rule. But at last I 
found an expression that is non-negative, which means convexity.

Can you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Try to look at the second derivative of $x\mapsto f(x^2)$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: BTW, a plot of $x\mapsto f(x)$ suggest that it is a convex function (so you made a mistake in your derivative).

Comment: Thank you. In fact I tried that, and that was non-negative, too.

Comment: Yes, but the authors claim it is concave of x^2, not of x

Comment: what does "concave of $x^2$" mean?

Comment: That is exactly the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you don't need second derivatives, since from:

$$ \cosh z=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1+\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right)\tag{1} $$
(the Weierstrass product for the hyperbolic cosine function) it follows that:
$$ \log\cosh z = \sum_{n\geq 0}\log\left(1+\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right)\tag{2}$$
and every term in the RHS of $(2)$ is for sure a concave function with respect to $z^2$.

Comment: Thank you. But I must say I cannot understand this, could you please explain the relationship between the f(x) in the title and  this product ? And, what does "concave w.r.t $x^2$" mean exactly, please ?

Comment: @yong: it is just what you are asking. We say that $f(z)=g(z^2)$ is a concave function with respect to $z^2$ if $g(z)$ is a concave function. Moreover, $e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}=2\cosh\frac{x}{2}$. Can you see the connection now?